# Is it possible to just have a condition by itself in a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

For example:

```
Char ch = ‘A’

for (ch <= 'Z')
{
    cout << ch;
    c++
}
```

All the examples I seen are like this:

```
for (ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
{
    cout << ch;
}
```

I searched on Google, but I didn't have any luck.

Comment: `ch = 'A'` isn't a condition. What do you mean? If I understand you correctly, the closest you can come is to make the first term in the `for` empty: `for (; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)`

Comment: A `for` looks like this: `for (initialization; condition; increase) statement;` So, you have only one condition. Actually a `for` could also be this way: `for(;;) { //do s.th. }`

Comment: It would be written like this `for (;ch <= 'Z'; ch++)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For loop consists of

```
for (init-statement; condition; iteration-expression)
```

You can easily skip initialization by writing

```
Char ch = ‘A’
for (;ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
{
    cout << ch;
}
```

You can also skip condition

```
Char ch = ‘A’
for (;; ch++)
{
    cout << ch;
    if (ch > 'Z') break;
}
```

Or the increase

```
Char ch = ‘A’
for (;;)
{
    cout << ch;
    if (ch > 'Z') break;
    ++ch;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to do this. The for structure is as follows:

```
for (init-statement; condition; iteration-expression)
```

If you don't need an init statement, the proper syntax using your example is:

```
for (; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
```